# Calculate places with flood risk during rain

Tags: hydrology

I want to evaluate a DEM to find out what places are likely to have standing water during heavy rainfall, based on topography and calculated water flows (see attached image). I have a sense I could use SAGA GIS but so far I haven't found the right tools. I would preferably also be able to see how deep the water would be in different places (different shades of blue in attached image) and amount of water going into the ground based on a map of pervious surfaces.

[image: Flood risk image]

Comment: Search "bluespot" on [esri learn](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/)?

Comment: That was helpful, it led my to down some interesting paths, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to hire a hydrologist since this is a complicated question with more variables than elevation. But if you want to proceed have a look at the [Sink tool in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sink.htm) Spatial Analyst or try the SAGA GIS [sink drainage route detection](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/ta_preprocessor_1.html)